# Can matchCriteria NONE in GetVerifiedStatus API call?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

As per [Paypal Doc's](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) `matchCriteria` can be `NONE` only for for certain financial institutions, what does it mean ?

With sending `firstName` & `lastName` empty values and `matchCriteria` as `NONE` in sandbox environment I'm getting expected response from API call, will this also work in live environment too ? I want to know this before moving my code to production and I didn't found clear information regarding this on doc's.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a business application requesting this service to PayPal so they can grant you access. PayPal reviews the different services you are requesting and grants an APP-ID that can be used for API calls. matchCriteria=NONE is an advanced permission.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/